# Filter out non-alphabetic characters from a list of words

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, interview-questions

For coding practice / interview exercises, I'd like to know if there's an optimizaton I can make to the following, where I "clean" a given word to remove punctuation or other characters that are not within "a" to "z".

There are some great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) to remove punctuation from a string, so my question today is not the best way how to do this, but instead whether there is an optimization I can make to my 3 lines of code below in the `word_count_engine` function? Can I do this in 1 or 2 lines or make the code more efficient so it doesn't loop over the list twice (i.e. with 2 list comprehensions)?

```
def clean(word):
    returnword = ""
    for letter in word.lower():
        if letter >= 'a' and letter <='z':
            # not out of bounds
            returnword += letter
    return returnword


def word_count_engine(document):

    words = document.split() # if there are     extra    spaces, split() still filters empty words out FYI
    words = [clean(word) for word in words] # a word like "$33!" will result in an empty string though
    words = [word for word in words if word] # so filter out empty strings and get the final list of clean words

document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only get Perfect by practice. just practice! $544 test"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Python strings are immutable, appending one character at a time using `+=` is inefficient.  You end up allocating a new string, copying all of the old string, then writing one character.

Instead, `clean()` should be written like this:

```
def clean(word):
    return ''.join(letter for letter in word.lower() if 'a' <= letter <= 'z')
```

Note that Python supports double-ended inequalities.

The name of your `word_count_engine` function poorly describes what it does.  In fact, the function doesn't print or return anything, so it's all dead code.  If I had to rewrite it, though, I'd say:

```
words = [word for word in map(clean, document.split()) if word]
```

Also consider replacing all of this code with a simple [regular expression substitution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I learn more than I expect through Stack Exchange thanks to people like you! Re: name of function - sorry, it's because the function is actually for something more detailed than I have described, and the above lines are just the first few lines of the function. I should have made that clear in the question/renamed it. I'll practice with regex functions next.